# Integrals with undefined points.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Suppose I have a function $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x$ }\in(0,1) \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}, f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$$

Is $\int_0^{1}f$ defined? I feel like it should be, as it is an area.
But its primitive function is not defined on 1 according to the domain. (Although it can be computed.) If so, what if the primitive function really is not defined, meaning I would get an error (one I won't happen to get here) computing the undefined points? 
I would appreciate your hypothetical supplies.

Comment: Have a look at [Lebesgue integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) somehow Lebesgue had a similar intuition as your on this point :).

Comment: What does $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ indicate since $f(1)$ is undefined? I simply don't understand.

Comment: @Vim we probably have $f(x)=x$ for $x\in (0,1]$.

Comment: I am sorry. That isn't the domain actually. However, that was the domain of another question I was dealing with, and the function wasn't defined on 1. It got me confused, leading me to ask this very question, in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ defined like that and just don't know the value at $x=1$, then the integral (Riemann, Lebesgue) is defined, since it does not depend on the value at isolated points.

If $f$ is only defined on $[0,1)$ you have a purely formal problem, but you can still extend it (arbitrarily) to $[0,1]$ and reason as before.

In general, you will define an integral as a map from a (well defined) set $X$ of functions to, e.g., $\mathbb{R}$ and to answer this kind of question you need to know criteria to figure out whether a given function belongs to $X$. For the common integral definitions the values of such $f$ on sufficiently 'small' sets is irrelevant.

Comment: I can I do such a thing?
May I add a point? And if I may, how do I add it?
This is my main problem...

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel Whether _you_ in particular may add a point is not what is relevant here. The definition of the integral (assuming we are using Riemann or Lebesgue integral) allows a certain amount of uncertainty with regard to the definition of the functions you want to integrate. In particular changing the value of an otherwise well behaved function in an arbitrary way in a single point simply does not matter. The integral will be defined regardless of the change and the value of the integral will not depend on the value chosen for the function in that (single) point.